# Update a row in Dataverse

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

Hi i'm trying to update a row in Dataverse but it giving me this error
**"Resource not found for the segment 'cdm_company'"**

I tried some things but not working
here i get the column

[image]

and here my script

[image]

And here's the response

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with lookups you have to use the LogicalCollectionName. It is usually the table's LogicalName with a string appended depending on the table's last character. If table LogicalName ends with:

- 'y', replace the 'y' with 'ies' (e.g. cdm_compan***y*** => cdm_compan***ies***)
- 's', append 'es' (e.g. bookingstatu***s*** => bookingstatus***es***)
- any other append 's' (account => account***s***)

The value that you need to store in your variable is only the ***GUID*** and you need to remove the slash at the beginning, please use one of the syntaxes below:

- cdm_companies/**variable**  [e.g cdm_companies/eb85465b-cdd6-4ef4-9e4b-9c632b0964af]
- cdm_companies(**variable**) [e.g cdm_companies(eb85465b-cdd6-4ef4-9e4b-9c632b0964af)]

Additionally, seems like the value you are retrieving is for Business unit, which should be from businessunit table but you are using the cdm_company table, are you sure this is the right table/column you need to update or to retrieve the value from? If you still have issues can you explain how the tables schema is?